# TFS 2013.4 - Unable to create team proejct from VS 2013.4

Tags: visual-studio-2013

```
Error 
TF30170: The plugin Microsoft.ProjectCreationWizard.TestManagement failed during task TestResolutionState from group TestManagement.
```

Explanation

> Plugin error text: “System.MissingFieldException: Field not found:
>   'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Common.WitCategoryRefName.SharedDataSet'.
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestManagementTeamProject.get_SharedParameterDataSetWorkItemTypeName()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestManagementTeamProject.get_HasSupportForSharedParameterDataSets()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestManagementTeamProject..ctor(TestManagementService
>   manager, String projectName) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestManagementService.b__0(String
>   name) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.ObjectCache`2.Get(Key
>   key, Creator creator) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.TestManagementService.GetTeamProject(String
>   projectName) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.PcwPlugin.ContextWrapper.get_Project()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.PcwPlugin.PcwPluginComponentCreator.SetPermissionsIfNeeded(ContextWrapper
>   wrapper) at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.PcwPlugin.PcwPluginComponentCreator.Parse(ContextWrapper
>   wrapper, XmlNode taskXml, Boolean fExecute)”

User Action

Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator.

Comment: Have you googled this?

Comment: @Just now i encountered same issue with VS 2013.4>>> any help...did Google but not much help.

Answer (score 3):

I just saw this exact problem (TFS 2013 Update 4 and Visual Studio 2013 Update 4).  I found the solution posted [here](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/850264/tf30162-task-testresolutionstate-from-group-testmanagement-failed) on the Microsoft Connect site solved the problem.  In short, uninstalling some assemblies that were mistakenly installed got everything working again.

```
1. Close all instances on Visual Studio and Microsoft Test Manager
2. Open Visual Studio command prompt in admin mode.
3. Perform the following steps:
   ngen uninstall Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client
   ngen uninstall Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Common
```

Comment: This even works with Visual Studio 2013 without any updates, thx!

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this issue when the version of Visual Studio is not upgraded to Update 4 and an attempt is made to create a new team project. I would suggest that you first make sure that the version of visual studio (that you use to create the new team project) is on the same version as TFS (in this case Update 4).

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaroud on msdn [forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b9d78b45-0ec2-4723-9bd1-6511cc3b003d/again-tf30170-the-plugin-microsoftprojectcreationwizardworkitemtracking-failed-during-task-wits?forum=tfsgeneral)

> There is a bug in the V1.0 version of the product that impacts Team
>   Project creation when the Team Foundation Administrators group has a
>   TFS project level group in its hierarchy.  One way that this might
>   occur is if you try to open the system up by adding the Team
>   Foundation Valid Users group to the Team Foundation Administrators
>   group, though any TFS project level group will trigger the condition
>   (e.g., [project A]\Project Administrators).  This issue only impacts
>   Team Project creation and it can be worked around by temporarily
>   removing the TFS project level group from the Team Foundation
>   Administrators group.  There is a variation on this Team Project
>   creation bug that will appear if the sync process runs across a user
>   that does not have a valid security identifier.  I am not quite sure
>   if your case of deleted domain users triggers this condition, but I
>   will follow up to find out.  In the meantime, please take a look at
>   the membership of your Team Foundation Administrators group to see if
>   there are any TFS project level groups in the hierarchy.

I don't know if Microsoft had realeased a patch for this bug but for now I choosed to return to TFS 2012 which works like a charm